# Trouble understanding what is included when using "greater than or equal to" (>=)

Tags: python, quicksort

I need to write a quicksort function for my course.
One possible solution given afterwards was this:

```
def quicksort(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return s
    else:
        return quicksort([x for x in s[1:] if x < s[0]]) \
        +[s[0]] \
        + quicksort([y for y in s[1:] if y >= s[0]])


list = [5, 6, 8, 2, 7, 1] #any numbers you want
print(quicksort(list))
```

Why is the `+[s[0]]` needed? isn´t it already included in `y >= s[0]`?

Comment: No because that condition is applied to `s[1:]` - where `s[0]` is already excluded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have multiple identical elements in your list, and you should not lose them in the process of sorting them.

Note that both of the comprehensions (which gather the elements "before" and "after" the pivot in terms of sorting) operate on `s[1:]`, i.e. every element after `s[0]`.  They will therefore never include `s[0]` itself, regardless of what other predicates you apply.

The `>=` is there because if you only included `> s[0]` on one side and `< s[0]` on the other, you would lose any other elements that `== s[0]` in the process of doing your sort.

For example:

```
# don't give variables the same name as built-in types/functions!
numbers = [5, 5, 5, 6, 8, 2, 7, 1]
print(quicksort(numbers))
```

```
[1, 2, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

What if we make it `y > s[0]` instead?

```
def quicksort(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return s
    else:
        return (
            quicksort([x for x in s[1:] if x < s[0]])
            + [s[0]]
            + quicksort([y for y in s[1:] if y > s[0]])
        )


# don't give variables the same name as built-in types/functions!
numbers = [5, 5, 5, 6, 8, 2, 7, 1]  # any numbers you want
print(quicksort(numbers))
```

```
[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Whoops!

Using `>=` isn't necessarily the only way to fix this.  We could explicitly have the middle part of our list be all the elements equal to the pivot (including the pivot), for example:

```
def quicksort(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return s
    p = s[0]  # could be any arbitrary element!
    return (
        quicksort([x for x in s if x < p])
        + [x for x in s if x == p]
        + quicksort([x for x in s if x > p])
    )
```

This might be a little slower because you're now doing an extra iteration through the list (maybe the fact that you're passing the second `quicksort` a shorter list makes up for it, though?) but perhaps makes the concept a little clearer that all the "less than" elements come before the "equal" elements which come before the "greater than "elements.

This approach also makes it easier to experiment with selecting different pivot points; if you happen to start with a list that's already sorted (or mostly sorted), for example, picking a pivot in the middle instead of at the beginning can be quite a bit quicker because your tree of recursive calls is more broad and less deep.

Comment: Thank you very much, I miss quit often the fact, that the "position-counter" in a list starts at zero. Was literally reading half an hour through the programm, looking if I had missed something.